Classification of Model Structures on Set
Has anyone published classifications of model structures and/or weak factorization systems on the category $\mathcal{Set}$? If so, where?
Context
Arising from the question whether the model structures on certain presheaf categories can be understood as Reedy model structures (these have been answered in the negative in the meantime), I started to think about which model structures might be imposed on $\mathcal{Set}$ at all. As far as I can tell, there are 6 weak factorization systems and 9 model structures [0], of which 1 is trivial (i.e. $(\mathsf{Hom}, \mathsf{Iso}, \mathsf{Hom})$), 6 are semi-trivial (i.e. of the form $(L, \mathsf{Hom}, R)$ for a WFS $(L, R)$) and 2 have the weak-equivalence-classes “empty” and “inhabited” [1]. Now, this classification was not particularly hard, so assuming I have not made any mistake, I would expect countless others to have performed it before me, but when I went to look up any references to save on the few hours of work it took nonetheless (respectively, afterwards, to check I got it right), I came up empty.

[0]: Assuming the axiom of choice.
[1]: One of them is described in the first paragraph of this mathoverflow question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/10246


Omar Antolín Camarena wrote up a proof: https://www.matem.unam.mx/~omar/notes/modelcatsets.html
